# React useState isn't setting opposite boolean correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple button on page with onClick event, and then useState hook that is by default set to false. Then I have elements on page, when I click on them I wanna do an action, but only if the state of that useState hook is set to true, which is done by if condition, but for some reason it passes it, even though the state should be false. My code:

Initiating the hook:

```
    const [ isEraser, setIsEraser ] = useState(false);
```

Setting state on button click:

```
<span
    className="scroll"
    onClick={() => {
        setIsEraser((isEraser) => !isEraser);
    }}
>
```

The condition:

```
console.log('Eraser is set to', isEraser);
if (isEraser == true) {
    // Code
}
```

The output of the console.log:

1. no changing state (is default false) -> false
2. changing state to true -> true
3. changing state back to false and triggering that event in which the condition is -> false, true, false

Edit:
I can't pass full component code, because it's kinda big, and some parts of code are protect by client contract, but the condition is in onClick event:

```
    $body.on('click', '.tvs-annotated-text, .tvs-annotate-element', function(
        e
    ) {
        console.log('Eraser is set to', isEraser);
        if (isEraser === true) {
            setIsAlert(1);
            // Odstraníme vybranému elementu backround
            this.style.backgroundColor = '';
            this.classList.remove('tvs-annotated-text');
            this.classList.remove('tvs-annotate-element');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `setIsEraser(!isEraser)`

Comment: Use three equals `===` for a strict equality comparison.

Comment: And where is your condition written?

Comment: @trash_dev the problem though isn't with type, but I tried that it sill doesn't work

Comment: Can you please put the full component code? Where is the `if` condition written?

Comment: The problem is likely a stale event handler. Updating the state won't necessarily update the event handler you bind to `.tvs-annotated-text, .tvs-annotate-element`, and thus `isEraser` inside that function will continue to refer to an older value. If an event handler depends on component state, it usually has to be removed and bound again whenever that value changes. Or you can use a reference instead. Please provide a more complete example. Without it it's impossible to pinpoint what changes to make.

Comment: @MichalGally Its a BAD BAD BAD idea to manipulate DOM in react

Comment: @Rajesh I'm aware of that, but it's required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, so the problem was that the onClick trigger was written in jQuery, after rewriting it to normal javascript it works now. Big thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you just need to do `setIsEraser(!isEraser)`

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried that initially, and then tried to update it functionally, it still doesn't work

Comment: @MichalGally Can you create a working snippet? If not, try to write a `useEffect(() > {}, [ isErase ])` and check if you are getting proper values here. If yes, then there is something wrong somewhere else

Comment: if the new state depends on the previous state, it should be updated using the old state: `setIsEraser(isEraser=> !isEraser)`

Comment: @Rajesh in useEffect I'm getting correct logs, same as we are updating the class of the icon in that span to change color, both works correctly, the problem should be in condition, but I just don't see it there

Comment: @MichalGally Problem is not in condition but how you reach there. I see you are using DOM manipulation and possibly jQuery. That is a bad idea. my suggestion is to create a function say `updateStylesOnClick(isErase)` and call it from `useEffect`

Comment: Both code fragments do the same thing here

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a function to set state `setIsEraser((isEraser) => !isEraser);` → `setIsEraser(!isEraser)`

Comment: Both code fragments do the same thing here

Answer (score -1):

In the setIsEraser you need to pass the last state. you passed the initial state in it so every time you press the button it passes false as isEraser.

change the isEraser in setIsEraser function to something else like pre or previous, etc.

```
<span
  className="scroll"
  onClick={() => {
      setIsEraser((pre) => !pre);
  }}
>
```

In this way pre would be the last state not the initial state and your program will work just fine.